# Synchronize creation of rows between tables

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have two tables, `posts`(`id_pk`,`title`) and `posts_content`(`post_id_pk`,`blob`). Whenever I create a row in `posts`, I want a complimentary row to be created in `posts_content`, with the same `id`. If I just use `auto_increment` on both, when two posts are created simultaneously, they might get switched. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have this:

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    title varchar(100),
    primary key (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE posts_content
(
    post_id int not null,
    blobdata blob,
    primary key (post_id),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_posts` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES posts (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You could perhaps run the two INSERTs like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO posts (title) VALUES ('some-title');
SET @GivenPostID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO posts_content (post_id,blobdata)
VALUES (@GivenPostID,'oxbdsixds');
COMMIT;
```

Give it a Try !!!