# MS Access: automatic creation of row in a table based on field in another table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a Table A with an `ID` field and a `Question` field. The question has a yes/no answer.

I want MS Access to automatically create a new observation (row) in another table, Table B, if I answer yes. How do I do this?

Ideally, I would also like the link between the two tables to be the 'ID' field, which is the primary key of Table A.

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36891/synchronize-creation-of-rows-between-tables) is vaguely similar, but is not in MS Access.